# what is the error in this web app script to give the desired effect?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQBUz.png)we've tried to write a script for a web app to a specific spreadsheet
the code is 2 files one in js

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page");
}

//function userClicked(name) {
  //var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T3AX_YBC8703g6N7sKot41tXUh6XN4zpcBF2V-_7iJ8/edit#gid=0";
  //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  //var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  //ws.appendRow([name])
  //Logger.log(name + "Clicked Run Button");
//}

function userClicked() {
  Logger.log("Someone Clicked the button");
}
```

and the other in html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <button id="btn">RUN !!</button>

    <script>
      function doSomething() {
                google.script.run.code.userClicked();
              }

      document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doSomething());
 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

we can't get the desired action when run button is clicked
we don't know if it's the declaration of functions or summoning them

please help guide to rectify the error

this is yje project link for further analysis
https://script.google.com/d/1daP7bLBlL46av4Wc6-Pr9-z9lg6JyMY44FUtfA08fnKRKLeMuCTxH3LY/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: In a more complex webapp you may wish to wrap your listeners in any event that occurs after the DOM is created to make sure that target of the adListener actually exists.

Comment: Add the web-browser,  script executions logs, the web app deployment settings, the spreadsheet sharing settings as well a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: both browsers firefox and chrome is used in this question
the rest of parameters are defaults

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Google Script client side API documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run), the path to call the App Script function is `google.script.run.yourFunction()` so in your html file. Also you are invoking the function straight away and passing the result of it to `addEventListener()`, instead of passing the function itself. The script should be this:

```js
function doSomething() {
                google.script.run.userClicked();
              }

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doSomething);
```

Comment: still don't produce the log desired as scripted in userClicked function

Comment: I spotted another slight scripting mistake, please review my further edit.

Comment: after the last edit it didn't summon userClicked function also
I've published the project link in question edit to help more analysis

Comment: What do you mean by "summon userClicked function"? I've just copied over your project and I do get "Someone Clicked the button" in the Cloud logs after a second after I clicked  the RUN!! button.

Comment: that's right, i just tried it and it works, when i tried it an hour ago, it simply didn't, that's upvote